# How to randomly sample web pages from a domain?

Tags: url, random, web-scraping, html

I'm trying to randomly sample *x* number of pages from a given domain. Say, for example, I'm looking at PubMed. Given just the URL `https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/`, is there any way to grab subpages randomly?

I typically use Python for this sort of thing, but I'm up for any tools in any language to look into this further!

Comment: Do you have the links to all subpages in an Database?

Comment: @SarahTrees so in some cases I might have unique identifiers (for example, PubMed IDs), but even in those cases, I don't have all of them nor do I know of a way to randomly sample from them... So... No?

Comment: Proposal: Separate the whole project into individual goals!
1. Find all the relevant URLs of a page
2. Save URL's this in a database
3. Select a url with the help of "random" of the programming language used or per SQL (recommended)
4. grab the content the selectet url.

I'm sure you can do it through Phyton, why not.

Start with step 1 and if you need help, post your problem with the code that is causing problems. This is the best way to get concrete help. I wish you success!